# 97 Chevy Tahoe front inside brake pad gone rotor bruised badly outside pad good?

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, tahoe

Started hearing and feeling

grinding sound coming from front of vehicle so when got free time jacked up the truck pull the tires off to check the brakes driver side inside brake pad which just metal and inside of rotor was grooved badly

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What exactly are you asking here?

Answer (score 1):

Check the slider pins on the caliper brackets. If they are frozen, this will cause the only one pad to wear out on each side.

Answer (score 0):

Going by your info, then you need to fit 2 new discs and a set of pads to remedy the situation.

And, before you ask, yes you need to change both discs with a new set of pads otherwise the braking will be out of balance : thats the reason pads are sold in axle sets not individually .

You should / must also check to make sure the caliper and pistons are moving correctly.